# How to update a specific characters of column value for all tables in a database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update a specific characters of  column value for all tables in a database in Sql server 2008. I have `_WORKGROUPNAME` column in my all tables and I want to change some characters in `_WORKGROUPNAME` in all tables of database.

sample data for `_WORKGROUPNAME` column

```
COWAI1
COWAI2
PMWAI1
PMWAI2
```

need results

```
COXXX1
COXXX2
PMXXX1
PMXXX2
```

I want to change WAI to XXX. and I am tying below SQL.

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME + ' 
SET _WORKGROUPNAME = N''XXX'  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON 
T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME ='_WORKGROUPNAME' 
WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME
```

but the problem is above statement is updating all column value to `XXX`, but I want to change only WAI to XXX.
How to achieve this.

**Edit :**

In all tables _WORKGROUPNAME name contains data and WAI will comes after 2 characters. and after WAI it is a number that can be any number.

For Example

```
ASWAI1500
WEWAI900000
ASWAI96
DDWAI11111
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at REPLACE or STUFF function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 'UPDATE ' + T.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + T.TABLE_NAME + ' 
SET _WORKGROUPNAME = replace(_WORKGROUPNAME,''WAI'',''XXX'')'  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T 
INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C ON 
T.TABLE_NAME = C.TABLE_NAME AND c.COLUMN_NAME ='_WORKGROUPNAME' 
WHERE T.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' ORDER BY T.TABLE_SCHEMA, T.TABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add `AND _WORKGROUPNAME = N'WAI'` to your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: what do you mean by "part data"

Comment: for example SET _WORKGROUPNAME = N''COXXX1'

Comment: So why can't you just set it to that?

Comment: all tables have some values like ABWAI222, just need to update WAI to XXX

Comment: How about if you change `SET _WORKGROUPNAME = N''XXX'` to `SET _WORKGROUPNAME = REPLACE(_WORKGROUPNAME, N'WAI', N'XXX')`